# How to combine two array values at a particular index from two different arrays

Tags: ios, arrays

I want two take the values at index 0 from two separate arrays and combine them together. For example, let's say the value at index 0 for array1 is NSNumber 5 and the value at index 0 for array2 is NSNUmber 7, how can I get a integer that says that the sum of the two values is 12? I'm just looking for a general answer but this is the code I have so far

```
NSNumber *j = [self.array1 objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber *k = [self.array2 objectAtIndex:0];
```

I can't just simply add the two, but what do I have to do to allow me to add them?

Comment: Are the numbers integers, floats, etc?

Comment: j.integerValue will give you the integer value so you can add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If them are NSNumber and you want another NSNumber, you must to do:

```
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[self.array1 objectAtIndex:0] intValue] + [[self.array2 objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];
```

Or using modern Objective C syntax, this can be shortened significantly.

```
NSNumber *n = @([self.array1[0] intValue] + [self.array2[0] intValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're integers, you can use:

```
NSInteger result = [j integerValue] + [k integerValue];
```

See the [NSNumber Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/integerValue) if they're stored as other types.